# React Native - Refresh current expendable list view screen using class component?

Tags: react-native

My code for expendable list view using class component. i want to referesh screen on press of button press.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LayoutAnimation, RefreshControl, StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView, UIManager, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
class ExpandableItemComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      layoutHeight: 0,
    };
  }


  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.item.isExpanded) {
      this.setState(() => {
        return { layoutHeight: null };
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(() => {
        return { layoutHeight: 0 };
      });
    }
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.layoutHeight !== nextState.layoutHeight) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  refreshScreen = (od_id) => {
    let order_id = od_id;
    var dataToSend = {
      order_id: order_id,
    };
    var formBody = [];
    for (var key in dataToSend) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[key]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join('&');
    fetch('Api call update status', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formBody,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        if (responseJson.status == 'true') {
          this.setState({ successtext: 'Order Cancelled.' });
          this.setState({ apiStatus: true });
        } else {
          this.setState({ errortext: 'Something went wrong.' });
        }
      });
  }
  render() {
    let order_no = '';
    if (this.props.item.orderno != '') {
      order_no = 'ORDER : OD' + this.props.item.orderno;
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={this.props.onClickFunction} style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={(styles.headerText, { flex: 1 })}>{order_no}</Text>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1 }}>{this.props.item.order_status}</Text>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', flex: 1 }}> {this.props.item.order_date} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ height: this.state.layoutHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.content}>
              <Text style={styles.text}> {' '}{this.props.item.item_list.replace(/\s+/g, '  ')}{' '} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}> {' '}{this.props.item.address.trim()}{' '} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}> {this.props.item.note.trim()} </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={(styles.cancelBtn, { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' })} >
              {(this.props.item.order_status == 'Processing' || this.props.item.order_status == 'Delivered') ? null : <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => { this.refreshScreen(this.props.item.id) }} >Cancel</Text>}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default class OrderListScreenCustomer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
    this.state = {
      listDataSource: [],
      userId: '',
      apiStatus: false,
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const output = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
    this.setState({ userId: output });
    const response = await fetch("Api call get list?userid=" + output, {
      "method": "GET",
    })
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      listDataSource: responseJson,
    });
    console.log(output);
  }
  updateLayout = (index) => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    const array = [...this.state.listDataSource];
    array[index].isExpanded = !array[index].isExpanded;
    this.setState(() => {
      return { listDataSource: array, };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.listDataSource.map((item, key) => (
            <ExpandableItemComponent key={item.id} onClickFunction={this.updateLayout.bind(this, key)} item={item} />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  topHeading: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
    padding: 16,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  separator: {
    height: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: '#808080',
    width: '95%',
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#606070',
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  content: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Please explain what error you receive from your current code and which button should execute the refresh action?

Comment: Cancel button update the status onPress and refresh screen.

Comment: See refreshScreen function its update order status but not refresh current screen on Cancel button onPress

Comment: ```refreshScreen``` update the status but ```ExpandableItemComponent ``` does not get the updated status because that is given to it from its parent in prop. You have to update the prop in order to update the content of ```ExpandableItemComponent ``` when order status changed.